# Неправильные вычисления при попытке найти сторону по двум сторонам и углу в СИ

Tags: c, математика, геометрия, double

Столкнулась с такой проблемой: при вычислении третьей стороны треугольника показывает неправильный ответ.  Вот часть кода, где это не работает:

```c
double prevodSUS(double a1, double a2, double a3) {
  double rad = 0, strana1 = 0, tmp = 0;

  if (a2 > 90) {
    tmp = 180 - a2;
    a2 = tmp;
  }

  rad = (a2 * M_PI) / 180;
  strana1 = sqrt(pow(a1, 2) + pow(a3, 2)- (2 * a1 * a3 * fabs(cos(rad))));
  return strana1;
}

int main() {
  double a1, a2, a3;

  a1 = 587;
  a2 = 93.084617194859987;
  a3 = 702;

  a2 = prevodSUS(a1, a2, a3);
  printf("a2 je %lf", a2);

  return 0;
}
```

Сторона должна быть 939, а выводит, что она  890.51951. 
Всем заранее большое спасибо за любой ответ или  предположение!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот это телодвижение

```
if (a2 > 90) {
    tmp = 180 - a2;
    a2 = tmp;
}
```

лишнее, как и `fabs` тут:

```
strana1 = sqrt(pow(a1, 2) + pow(a3, 2)- (2 * a1 * a3 * fabs(cos(rad))));
```

Уберите, и все получится.

И еще - используйте нормальные имена (да и порядок передачи) переменных. Вот так, согласитесь, понятнее?

```
double prevodSUS(double edge1, double edge2, double angle )
{
    return sqrt(edge1*edge1 + edge2*edge2 - 2*edge1*edge2*cos(angle*M_PI/180));
}
```

Кстати, само имя функции - ну вот что должен подумать посторонний человек - что делает функция с именем `prevodSUS`?

Comment: Большое спасибо!!! И на счет имен переменных - я просто учусь на чешском языке (: Но впредь, если появятся вопросы, я обязательно буду переименововать функции/переменные, чтобы все было понятнее (: Спасибо!

Comment: @DontBeSoAngry *учусь на чешском языке* - тогда дело другое, извините за `strana` (но не за `a1`, `a2`, `a3` :))

Comment: @Harry: транслитом переменные называть все равно моветон ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Многие из нас, конечно, этим грешили в начале пути, но поощрять это точно не стоит :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Как я понимаю, `strana` - это сторона по-чешски, а чешский язык кириллицу не использует, так что говорить о транслите не приходится...

Comment: @Harry: условно, да, это не транслит. Но как Вы относитесь к коду а ля `auto сторона = ...`?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov При условии, что разрешены русские буквы? Совершенно нормально. А как англоязычные относятся к коду `auto edge = ...`?

Comment: Абсолютно спокойно они к нему относятся, ибо мешанины языков в данном случае не наблюдается.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Вот так и я относился бы, если бы были разрешены русские буквы :) Откровенно - не вижу никакого повода для дискуссии.

Comment: Начнём с того, что они разрешены. Но, даже если не брать во внимание, что это просто выглядит ужасно, работать-то с этим невозможно